# CComboBox::SetItemHeight() increases both the Item and control height

Tags: mfc, ccombobox

I am using a class that is the descendant of [`CComboBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx). The problem occurs when I call the [`CComboBox::SetItemHeight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs2b25yt.aspx) method to set the height of my combobox **items** using the following code:

```
m_searchComboBox.SetItemHeight(0,17);
```

It sets the height of Items but the height of the control (dropdown list) is also increased and the new height is larger than the height I set through Dialog Box. I also tried the following code:

```
m_searchComboBox.SetItemHeight(-1,17);
```

But that sets the height of the edit-control not the height of items. **What should I do to set the height of Combobox items without disturbing the height of dropdown list?**

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752486/how-to-change-the-apparent-height-of-a-combobox-control-with-the-dropdownlist-bu

Comment: Actually the height of the list is another thing than the height of the items, but I would not wonder if Windows implicitly changes the one with the other. To fix this I would try setting the list's height explicitly after changing the items' height. The list's height in fact is defined by the combox box' height, so try m_searchComboBox.MoveWindow() with according values.
(Probably I'm a bit late with this comment...)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.. anyways, better late than never :)