# Set height of edit box/static text area of MFC CComboBox (not the dropdown)

Tags: c++, mfc, ccombobox

My goal is to be able to programatically control the width and height of the combobox when it is closed (dropdown not displayed). I have various other controls, such as buttons, and I want all the controls to appear a uniform size on the dialog (say, 100 x 40). I tried calling `my_cb_device.SetItemHeight(-1,40)` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Style is CBS_DROPDOWNLIST. Can anyone furnish a simple example of changing this? Does CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT need to be set/not set? I've tried every combination I can think of, nothing seems to affect the height. Oddly, width is not uncooperative. Some code (note: `BTN_HT` is 40):

```
m_cb_device.Create( WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP |
    CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_VSCROLL | CBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT,
    dummyRect, this, ID_CB_DEVICE );
populate_device_dropdown();
m_cb_device.SetItemHeight( -1, BTN_HT );
m_cb_device.SetCurSel( 0 );
m_cb_device.SetMaxVisibleLines( 32 );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16832507/383779